# How to convert AFNI data to NIFTI data?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a AFNI image file called: `cortex+orig.HEAD` and `cortex+orig.BRIK`. I want to convert it to NIFTI file named: `cortex.nii`. Anybody can give me a help? Thanks!

Comment: Probably you would have to search for third party add-ons (e.g on Matlab File Exchange) for niche image formats like those.  To my knowledge Matlab doesn't handle them natively.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin 3dAFNItoNIFTI in AFNI should work for you.
In your situation:

`3dAFNItoNIFTI cortex+orig. -prefix cortex.nii`

See details below.
http://afni.nimh.nih.gov/pub/dist/doc/program_help/3dAFNItoNIFTI.html